# Affine variety consisting $(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)$ should be equal to whole affine space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[Vanishing ideal of points. Concrete example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4366863/1015445)

In this question I was searching to find vanishing ideal of $$\{(n,n)| n\in\mathbb Z\}\subset A^2(\mathbb C)$$

I thought that vanishing ideal is $$\left<\prod_{n\in\mathbb Z}(x-n)(y-n)\right>$$

But it is not clearly a polynomial in $\mathbb C[x,y]$

My guts say that the vanishing ideal should be $\emptyset\subset \mathbb C[x,y]$

but having a bit hard time where to start and how to show it actually.

Comment: The vanishing ideal is $(x - y)$.

Comment: but how you prove it

Comment: By the transform $(x,y) \to (x - y, y)$ it suffice to show that the vanishing ideal of $(0, Z)$ is $(x)$. If a polynomial $f(x,y)$ vanish on $(0, Z)$ then write $f(x,y) = xg(x,y) + h(y)$. We have $h(Z) = 0$ so $h = 0$, thus $f \in (x)$.

Comment: but it also vanishes on (z,z) for every z\inC

Comment: Yes, because the Zariski closure of $\{(n,n): n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is $\{(n,n): n \in \mathbb{C}\}$.